# react- native: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, react-native

Am new to react-native android app development. Please help me solve this issue.

Am not able to run my first application, am getting error as `adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I checked inside android sdk->platform-tools->i can see adb.exe there.

Build is successfull but getting error during run time. Below is my `cmd prompt`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
E:\ReactWorkSpace\MyFirstApp>react-native run-android
Scanning 560 folders for symlinks in E:\ReactWorkSpace\MyFirstApp\node_modules (72ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0434Library
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Running dex in-process requires build tools 23.0.2.
For faster builds update this project to use the latest build tools.
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug
:app:assembleDebug
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'A16 - 4.2.2' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 7 mins 4.412 secs
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Starting the app (D:\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.myfirstapp/.MainActivity...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.myfirstapp/.MainActivity }

E:\ReactWorkSpace\MyFirstApp>
```

Am not using emulator, am using my own mobile device. App is launched in my device but all i see is a white blank screen. I followed all the instructions properly as mentioned in the official website.

Thank you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

All you have to do is add the adb path in system variable.

Copy the adb location, and goto Controlpanel->System->Advnaced System Settings->Environment Variables->Under System Variables you will find `PATH` variable, selct that first and click on Edit, then click on New and paste your adb path, now click Ok. Thats it problem solved.

Now restart your command prompt, and run `react-native run-android`. It works:)

Hope this helps someone. Thanks for checking out my question.

Comment: Where do I find the adb path?

Comment: @Operator, it would be in the folder where you installed it. If you have used android studio the ideal path is, C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe. Hence the path is where you save adb.exe file

Comment: in my case after adding the adb path in system variable, I had to restart my desktop

Answer (score 5):

It is based upon your IDE, If you are using Webstorm you have to go to Settings -->Appearance & Behaviors --> Path Variable. 
Now you will get the new window that might have been empty. Top-Right of the you will see "+" icon you have to select that one and set your variable.
My Variable is like:

**Name: ANDROID_HOME
Value: D:\Android_SDK\platform-tools.**

Answer (score 1):

You see blank screen because your server is not running or stopped

Did you run `adb reverse` if you are debugging using usb

try connecting laptop and mobile to same wifi and enter your ip:8081 in dev settings

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem many times and the given answers are definetly the way to fix it but i recently got this error again but the build was successful and i couldn't fix it this way. i found out it was a internet connection error with the emulator.

just restart the emulator if you have this and make sure you can go on the internet opening google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If your metro is already stared but getting this error.Run Command this =====>. `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`. App runs successfully on device.`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` If getting this kind of error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem and even if you're doing the steps correctly it will not run unless you will do this solution.

For react-native-cli, if you are running the updated version you must install a "Java 11" and if you are running old react native then try installing the "Java 8".

(note that u  will need to restart your system)