# my app js not working in react native. what my mistake?

Tags: android, react-native

I newbie for react native. when I learning to hello world in app.js. when I run for android "native-react run-android" build success but not working on my phone. not change
[image]

this is my code in app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

    const instructions = Platform.select({
    ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
    android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
    });

    type Props = {};
    export default class App extends Component<Props> {
render() {
    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>Hello, Steven Wiaji, S.Kom</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
  </View>
);
}}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
    },
    });
```

this is adb running
[image]

this is when i run on my phone
[image]

Comment: Have you saved the changes in the file above before react-native run-android command?

Comment: @angelos_lex yes. i am sure save my file. i. work with IDE atom

Comment: is your packager running ?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani how do i know my packager running?

Comment: when i uninstall my project and running again. it's same. not change to hello world

Comment: check if there is any terminal open with symbol of nodejs and what is inside it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code. Probably issue with node_modules. You might wanna delete the folder and do a `npm i` or `yarn` again.
Here's a working example.
https://snack.expo.io/S1oozjjUV

Comment: what folder to delete?

Comment: Aha, I see an adb issue. You might wanna look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567579/react-native-adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-opera